# Start aplicação ao desbloquear tela - Android Studio -RESOLVIDA

Tags: android

Tenho uma aplicação em android que roda em background. Acontece que ao **bloquear/desbloquear** a tela do celular, a aplicação para. Gostaria de saber se há como dar um start na aplicação assim que o usuario desbloquear a tela. Estou usando o `BootReceiver`.

Class:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent i = new Intent(context, MeuServico.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);

}
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver com minha resposta?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta utilizar assim:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println(intent.getAction());
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT))
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(context,MeuServico.class); 
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);        
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

Lembre-se de declarar no Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```